# How to retrieve my listpanier items to display them in html

Tags: javascript

hello I have a purchase order with items each time I add or remove an item my "listbasket object" is incremented by a new item
If I remove it, it has the opposite effect.
So it's really the best place to get the quantities of my items and display them on htm
So that for each article, I have the quantity in real time.

I tried the code below, but in the console of the cart var nothing is displayed.

```js
obj.listpanier = function() {
  var panierCopy = [];
  for (i in panier) {
    item = panier[i];
    itemCopy = {};
    console.log("item", item)
    for (p in item) {
      itemCopy[p] = item[p];
    }
    itemCopy.total = Number(item.prix * item.quantite).toFixed(decimal);
    panierCopy.push(itemCopy)
  }
  return panierCopy;
}

var panier = MonPanier.listpanier();

for (var i = 0; i < panier.length; i++) {

  var produit = panier[i].nom;
  var quantite = panier[i].quantite;
  console.log("quantitequantite", quantite)

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = '<span class="produit">' + produit + '</span>' +
    '<span class="quantite">' + quantite + '</span>';

  console.log("quantiteli", li)
  document.querySelector(".panier ul").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Produit 03 (12.00 €)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-end">
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" data-nom="Produit 03" data-prix="12.00" data-qte="1" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier">ajouter au panier</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-end">
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" data-nom="Produit 03" data-prix="12.00" data-qte="1" class="btn btn-primary retirer-panier">retirer-panier</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There are no `<ul>` elements in your HTML.

Comment: Thank you I had forgotten them, here they are, but that does not change anything my basket variable does not return anything

Comment: [your sample code is not effective...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: why is it not effective, I could put more coe but then this is refused by the site

Comment: I can give you my codpen https://codepen.io/flexi2202/pen/YzOZoXW